# Syntax error when I put DISTINCT Keyword in join query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting syntax error when I put `DISTINCT` Keyword  in join query

I use DISTINCT for the user `id` using join query

```
SELECT  `dev_test_team`. *, 
        DISTINCT `dev_user`.`user_id` as athlete_id, 
        `dev_user`.`user_type` 
FROM `dev_test_team`,`dev_user` 
JOIN `dev_test_teams_athlete` as `tt` ON  `dev_user`.`user_id` = `tt`.`user_id`
```

> SQL Syntex error is
>    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT `dev_user`.`user_id` as athlete_id, `dev_user`.`user_type` FROM `dev_te' at line 1

I am always getting this values using this query

```
SELECT `dev_test_team`.*,`dev_user`.`user_id` as `athlete_id`,
        `dev_user`.`user_type` 
FROM `dev_test_team`,`dev_user` 
JOIN `dev_test_teams_athlete` as `tt` ON `dev_user`.`user_id` = `tt`.`user_id`

team_id |team_name| user_id |athlete_id | user_type 
 1          team1     480       380         4
 2          team2     472       380         4
 1          team1     480       379         4
 2          team2     472       379         4
 3          team3     478       360         4
 4          team3     478       390         4
```

I want value like that values:-

```
team_id |team_name| user_id |athlete_id | user_type 
 1          team1     480       380         4
 2          team2     472       379         4
 3          team3     478       360,369     4
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT .....`

Comment: And you are using the old `FROM t1,t2` as well as a `JOIN` Use JOIN only so you need 2 `JOINS`

Comment: sir, i am unable to put DISTINCT in query team1,team2,team3 wants to remove dublicate values and wants single values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking to your expected  result  you should not use DISTINCT Clause but

semms you are looking for group_concat distinct

```
SELECT dev_test_tean.id, dev_test_team.name, dev_test_team.user_id, group_concat( distinct `dev_user`.`user_id`) as `athlete_id`,
        `dev_user`.`user_type` 
FROM `dev_test_team`
CROSS JOIN `dev_user` 
INNER JOIN `dev_test_teams_athlete` as `tt` ON `dev_user`.`user_id` = `tt`.`user_id`
GROUP BY dev_test_tean.id, dev_test_team.name, dev_test_team.user_id, `dev_user`.`user_type`
```